# Django gives IntergrityError, user.id NOT null, don't know why

Tags: python, django, forms, models, modelform

I'm trying to make am modelform that is used to send an email to change the email on a user entry, and for some reason it gives me `access_emailchangeauth.user_id may not be NULL` when I click submit on the form. I have no idea why.

code is below

```
def changeEmail(request):
    data = request.POST if request.method == 'POST' else None
    if data:
        form = ChangeEmailForm(data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(user=request.user)
        else:
            a = request.user
            a = u.objects.get(username__iexact=a)
            form = UserModificationForm(instance=a)
            form2 = ChangeEmailForm()
            return render('accounts/modify.html',{'form': form, 'form2': form2, 'usr': a})

#forms.py
class ChangeEmailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmailChangeAuth
        fields = ['new_email']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        self.user = user
        print user
        super(ChangeEmailForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
#models.py

class EmailChangeAuth(models.Model):
    auth_code = UUIDField(auto=True, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(u)
    new_email = models.EmailField(max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.auth_code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not included user in the list of fields, it will not be passed on to the ModelForm's instance constructor.

Thus, what you want here is to change the user attribute of the form's instance, not the attribute on the form object itself.  In .save(), change self.user to self.instance.user.  That should get you going.

However, I also want to suggest that this mechanism it generally an anti-pattern: why are you not allowing user to be a field on the ModelForm if it's a required field that you populate anyway?

Comment: I want user to be filled automatically, but not have a field. User is supposed to be the person logged in, and this is so if they want to change their email.

Comment: Also, yes that worked! If you know a way to fix the issue about the anti-pattern would you please tell me whenever you can?

Comment: Gotcha.  In that case, you probably don't want user in your save method, but to set it after you've validated the modelform in your view logic.  (In other words, put form.instance.user = request.user in your view before form.save())